# Trigger Modal and get "Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I'm making an ADD button to trigger Modal of React-Bootstrap using react-redux. once I click the ADD button. I got "Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined" error. My Modal component code looks like this:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

class PopUp extends Component {

render () {

  console.log(this.props.modal_open.show);
    return (

        <Modal show = {this.props.modal_open.show} >
            here goes <Modal> body
        </Modal>

        );
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PopUp);
```

I put console.log(this.props.modal_open.show) right before Modal tag. After I clicked ADD button, console shows 'true' so I should've had Modal opened. But I got the error.[image]

I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days. I've done a lot of online searches. I have no clue about this issue still. Hope someone could help me out!

Comment: can you show your "ADD" button logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you updated to React 16 (Fiber) this might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/issues/188). I'm still trying to figure out a solution that will work for me, but there are a couple of shims available on that issue page if you go through the comments, which might be useful to you.

Possibly related: [react-bootstrap's Modal does not work with React 16](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2812).